# Returning object array from service, directly from observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subscribe

I am fairly new to TypeScript and RxJS, so my understanding of observables and subscriptions are limited.

I am required to call a method from the service class that returns an object array (for now, it is being logged to the console), and I am to make this call in the component class after a button is clicked.

The problem that I am running into is that the array is returning as empty in the console when I try to assign it to a variable. However, when I log the result from the http.get method directly, I see my object array.

I was wondering what I'm overlooking here to get this sort of error, and what can I do to fix it so as to avoid running into this again?

**cars.model.ts**

```
export interface ICar {
    Make: string;
    Model: string;
    Year: string;
    Specifications: boolean[];
  }
```

**cars.new.mock.json**

```
[
    {
        "Make": "Honda",
        "Model": "CRV",
        "Year": "2021",
        "Specifications": [
            true,
            true,
            false,
            true,
            false
        ]
    },
    {
        "Make": "Toyota",
        "Model": "Camry",
        "Year": "2021",
        "Specifications": [
            true,
            true,
            false,
            true,
            false
        ]
    }
]
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<button (click)="shownewCars()">New Cars</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CarsService } from './services/cars.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  title = 'AutoZone';

  constructor(private carsService: CarsService){
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
  shownewCars(){
    this.carsService.logNewCarsMessage();
    console.log(this.carsService.returnNewCars());
  }

}
```

**cars.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ICar } from '../models/cars.model';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CarsService{
    carsURL = '/assets/cars.mock.json';
    newCarsURL = '/assets/cars.new.mock.json'
    private newCars: ICar[] = [];

    constructor(private http : HttpClient){}
    
    returnNewCars(): ICar[]{
        this.http.get<ICar[]>(this.newCarsURL).subscribe(result => {this.newCars = result});
        return this.newCars;
    }

    logNewCarsMessage(){
        this.http.get(this.newCarsURL).subscribe((responseData) => console.log("Console log New Cars: ", responseData));
    }
}
```

**Console**

```
[]
Console log New Cars: (2)[{...}, {...}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has to do with async code.

The `http.get(...)` function returns an `Observable<ICar[]>`, which will send the actual HTTP request when subscribed to.

The problem here is that the code doesn't wait till the HTTP response comes back from the server. `.subscribe(result => {this.newCars = result})` registers the callback function that should be executed once the HTTP call returns, but immediately continues without actually waiting.
The next line immediately returns the (at that moment) still empty `this.newCars` variable.

The reason the `logNewCarsMessage` function does work, is because that one only logs once the HTTP response arrives. As you can see in your console output, the `Console log New Cars: (2)[{...}, {...}]` line is printed **after** `[]`, while you call the `logNewCarsMessage` function **before** `returnNewCars`.

There are two ways you can solve this: Using Promises, or preferably using Observables.

#### RxJS Observables

Instead of returning the cars array directly, *return an Observable* that will eventually emit the cars array.

**cars.service.ts**

```
private newCars$: Observable<ICar[]>;

returnNewCars(): Observable<ICar[]> {
  this.newCars$ = this.http.get<ICar[]>(this.newCarsURL);
  return this.newCars$;
}
```

The $-sign in `newCars$` is not required, but it is a nice convention to signify that the variable is actually an Observable.

**app.component.ts**

```
shownewCars(): void {
  this.carsService.returnNewCars().subscribe(cars => console.log(cars));
}
```

#### Promises

You can use the `.toPromise()` function to turn an Observable into a Promise. This way you can use normal async/await syntax to use your asynchronous code in a synchronous looking way.
Again, I don't really recommend this way, because while it might look easier at first glance, it is a lot less powerful and *not the Angular or RxJS way*.

**cars.service.ts**

```
private newCars: ICar[] = [];

async returnNewCars(): Promise<ICar[]> {
  this.newCars = await this.http.get<ICar[]>(this.newCarsURL).toPromise();
  return this.newCars;
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
async shownewCars(): Promise<void> {
  const cars = await this.carsService.returnNewCars();
  console.log(cars);
}
```

**UPDATE for RxJS 7**

RxJS 7 deprecated the `.toPromise()` function. As an alternative you can use `lastValueFrom(myObservable$)`. The HTTP call in cars.service.ts would look like this:

```
this.newCars = await lastValueFrom(this.http.get<ICar[]>(this.newCarsURL));
```